# Cypress tests wirh circi ci for edge browser fails

Tags: cypress, microsoft-edge

I have been trying to setup the edge browser for cicle ci but yet it shows a error as(Any tips much appreciated. the code was woking for chrome and firefix and i have added edge and yet unable to work that out. thanks)

[image]

yml config as this:

```
  version: 2.1
    orbs:
      cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.29.0
    executors:
      with-chrome:
        docker:
          - image: 'cypress/browsers:latest'
      with-firefox:
        docker:
          - image: 'cypress/browsers:latest'
      with-electron:
        docker:
          - image: 'browsers/cypress-electron:latest'
      with-edge:
        docker:
          - image: 'cypress/browsers:node14.10.1-edge88'
    
    workflows:
      build:
        jobs:
          - cypress/install:
              install-command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-engines
    
          - cypress/run:
              name: Chrome
              yarn: true
              requires:
                - cypress/install
              executor: with-chrome
              browser: chrome
              post-steps:
                - run: ls
                - store_test_results:
                    path: results
                - store_artifacts:
                    path: cypress/screenshots
    
          - cypress/run:
              name: Firefox
              yarn: true
              requires:
                - Chrome
                - cypress/install
              executor: with-firefox
              browser: firefox
              post-steps:
                  - run: ls
                  - store_test_results:
                          path: results
                  - store_artifacts:
                          path: cypress/screenshots
    
          - cypress/run:
              name: Edge
              yarn: true
              requires:
                - Chrome
                - Firefox
                - cypress/install
              executor: with-edge
              browser: edge
              post-steps:
                  - run: ls
                  - store_test_results:
                    path: results
                  - store_artifacts:
                    path: cypress/screenshots
```

Comment: If you change the version by `cypress/browsers:node16.16.0-chrome107-ff107-edge`, is it better?

Comment: Many Thanks, this worked! also i did formating on yml code,